# Given a sample of input/output data, predict new outputs

Tags: regression, machine-learning

My problem is the following : I have a number of inputs with the corresponding deterministic outputs. There is no error on either input or output. The link between the two is completely unknown to me. With this information, what kind of mathematical technique should I use to get estimated outputs from new inputs ? Are we talking about machine learning, regression,... ? I am even confused about the mathematical field involved here, as statistics seem to give some tools for this kind of problem, but in my case everything is perfectly deterministic.

Comment: It seems that you need to use [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). I'm not versed in these, but there's plenty of info in the internet.

Comment: Question seems to belong in Cross Validated. By the way, Regression is a part of Machine Learning (supervised learning).

Answer (score 1):

Function **interpolation** is what you are trying to achieve. A standard method is to chose a basis of functions (for example polynomials of your input data, if you do polynomial interpolation) and express your input-output relationship as weighted sums of those functions. If you have $n$ known corresponding points, you can chose a basis of $n$ (independent) functions and find the $n$ weights by solving a linear system of $n$ equations.

Comment: I should have precised that both my inputs and outputs are **multidimensional**. So one input is a vector of 5 numbers and correspond to one output which is also a vector of 5 numbers. Therefore interpolating is probably difficult ?

Comment: So it's mutlivariate interpolation. See for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91828/multivariate-function-interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some caution to the other answers. While various interpolation and prediction techniques can work, they all come with assumptions about the process generating your outputs given inputs.

However, until you have an understanding of the system that's generating your data, you can't be confident in *any* approach or set of approximations.

So while there's various mathematical techniques you can apply, I recommend spending time learning how these numbers come to be.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer holds true for a single set of input and output. If you have a series of inputs, corresponding outputs and if you are interested in knowing the required input for a specific output then "machine learning" is the answer. I would start with artificial neural network.